# Where is my Steam directory?

Tags: directory, location

Where the hell is it?! I've been looking for ages and I can't find it! I want to find it so I can change the resolution of War Thunder as it doesn't have my native resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Steam directory here: ~/.steam/steam

You may need to show hidden files:
Edit >> preferences >> and tick the box that says "Show hidden and back up files"

Comment: When I go into my home there is only - Desktop, documents, downloads, Music, Pictures, Public (nothing in here), Templates, Videos and Examples. And when I did find my home name, it took me back to the home which doesn't really have anything useful.

Comment: Show hidden files. I'm booted to Lubuntu at the moment so it may be different for you (but only slightly, look around) and is under the "View" option (at the top) in the file manager. You can also open the terminal and type `locate steam` and find out where these files are hidden. Spend some time learning the file system, using a search engine, and figuring it out - you'll like it, but there is a learning curve. Linux is not Windows. :-) Anything like `.File/FolderName` is a "hidden" file.